# Injection and surjection over reals such that the composite are neither injection or surjection

Tags: calculus, functions, examples-counterexamples

> Can you give me an example of two functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that 
>   $$f\text{ is injective}\quad\text{and}\quad g\mbox{ is surjective}$$
>   but the composite $g\circ f$ is neither injective or surjective?.

In addition, if we have to injections $f:A\rightarrow B$, $g:B\rightarrow A$ how can I define a bijection between $A$ and $B$, I think that $h(x)=f(x)$ works for injection but I don't know how to write clear the surjectivity, I belive that given $b\in B$, it's enough to choose $a=g(b)$ but I don't know how to prove it correctly.

Comment: What functions have you considered thus far? Do you know any functions that are injective but not surjective? How about functions that are surjective but not injective? And functions that are neither? There are a bunch of trigonometric functions here that could be very helpful. (The last one does not require any trig at all) Also, I do not understand your paragraph that starts with "In addition" at all (maybe there are a few typos?).

Comment: Thank's, I'm from Mexico, and my english isn't good at all. I know very examples of this but not with all the real numbers, I've been triying with functions that gives $|x|$ or $x^2$ but, I always take an bijective with injective or surjective, and then I failed... Could you give some example?

Comment: yeah that is the right idea; arctan is a popular injective-but-not-surjective function on reals; tangent is a popular surjective-but-not-injective function on reals; however, if you compose them you get x back... squaring tangent also does not do the trick since tangent^2 isn't surjective anymore; try to think of what part of tangent you care about in g(f(x)) (remember f is not surjective!), and change the rest of the function g so that you have a surjective function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. An example of function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $g$ is surjective (but not injective) is 
$$g(x)=x(x-1)(x+1)=x^3-x.$$

Are you able to find an injective function $f$ (not surjective) such that the  $g\circ f$ is neither injective or surjective?

Comment: Such $g$ is not defined at $x=-1$. For $f$ try a strictly increasing function (not surjective) such that $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be an injective function with $\mathsf{im}f=(-1,1)$ (there are plenty).

Let $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be prescribed by $x\mapsto0$ if $x\in(-1,1)$, $x\mapsto x-1$ if $x\geq1$ and $x\mapsto x+1$ if $x\leq-1$.

Then $g$ is surjective and $g\circ f$ is constant.

Comment: To the proposer: Let the image of $f$ be  bounded and let $g$ map bounded sets to bounded sets and suppose  $g(y_1)=g(y_2)$ for some $y_1,y_2\in im(f)$ with $y_1\ne y_2.$  For example if $f:\Bbb R\to (0,3)$ is a bijection and $g(x)=(x-1)^3-(x-1),$ with $y_1=1$ and $y_2=2.$